# Installing OpenGL in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, opengl

I'd like to install OpenGL on my Debian live cd. I just need it to so a virtualbox windows guest can use it. It's a live cd so no changes will be saved, so the easiest way possible would be great. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My UI is LXDE.
Thanks

Comment: OpenGL implementation is driver-specific. It comes with the driver if you're using proprietary driver from nvidia/AMD, while open source drivers uses mesa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debian, OpenGL :

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

You may also want libglu1-mesa-dev, freeglut3-dev